# How to group an array by similar keys in php?

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

i have a dynamic array as

```
array(7) {
  ["question"]=>
  string(6) "test 1"
  ["question1"]=>
  string(12) "hello test 1"
  ["question2"]=>
  string(20) "hello test 2 checked"
  ["homepage2"]=>
  string(8) "homepage"
  ["question3"]=>
  string(14) "3 test checked"
  ["homepage3"]=>
  string(8) "homepage"
  ["question4"]=>
  string(20) "question 4 ? checked"
}
```

keys are "question", "question1"...etc
and "homepage","homepage1"..etc
so i want to display only the values from the array when the index is question($number) and has similar key as homepage($number)

like how to make it look like this

```
array(4) {
  ["question2"]=>
  string(20) "hello test 2 checked"
  ["homepage2"]=>
  string(8) "homepage"
  ["question3"]=>
  string(14) "3 test checked"
  ["homepage3"]=>
  string(8) "homepage"
}
```

Comment: Why not an indexed array (with numeric keys) where each entry is an associative array with two key/value pairs? That seems a more logical structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create an array keyed by the suffix numbers, and store as value an array of all key/value pairs where the key has that suffix number. Then you would filter those that have two such key/value pairs, and arrange those in the format you need:

```
$arr = [
  "question"=> "test 1",
  "question1"=> "hello test 1",
  "question2"=> "hello test 2 checked",
  "homepage2"=> "homepage",
  "question3"=> "3 test checked",
  "homepage3"=> "homepage",
  "question4"=> "question 4 ? checked",
];

$temp = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/^(question|homepage)(\d+)$/", $key, $parts))
        $temp[$parts[2]][$parts[0]] = $value;
}
$result = [];
foreach($temp as $num => $pair) {
    if (count($pair) == 2) $result = array_merge($result, $pair);
}

print_r($result);
```

`$result` will be:

```
Array (
    "question2" => "hello test 2 checked",
    "homepage2" => "homepage",
    "question3" => "3 test checked",
    "homepage3" => "homepage"
)
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/807955).

#### More logical structure

I would however suggest the more logical structure where you group question and homepage together in a pair (array), and assign that to a key which is the number of that pair. In that case the two loops need minor changes:

```
$temp = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/^(question|homepage)(\d+)$/", $key, $parts))
        $temp[$parts[2]][$parts[1]] = $value;
}
$result = [];
foreach($temp as $num => $pair) {
    if (count($pair) == 2) $result[$num] = $pair;
}
```

This will give the following structure:

```
Array(
    "2" => Array(
        "question" => "hello test 2 checked",
        "homepage" => "homepage"
    ),    
    "3" => Array(
        "question" => "3 test checked",
        "homepage" => "homepage"
    )
)
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/807958).

Comment: this is Perfect! However what if the $arr was multi array like

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["question0"]=>
    string(14) "test 1 checked"
    ["homepage0"]=>
    string(8) "homepage"
    ["question1"]=>
    string(12) "hello test 1"
    ["question2"]=>
    string(20) "hello test 2 checked"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["question0"]=>
    string(14) "check number 1"
    ["homepage0"]=>
    string(8) "homepage"
     }
}

this case it cant work

Answer (score -1):

Here's something that worked for me:

```
<?php
$homePageNum = 2;

$var =  array(
"question"=>
"test 1",
"question1"=>
"hello test 1",
"question2"=>
"hello test 2 checked",
"homepage2"=>
"homepage",
"question3"=>
"3 test checked",
"homepage3"=>
"homepage",
"question4"=>
"question 4 ? checked"
);

die($var['question'.$homePageNum]);

?>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @trincot this is Perfect! Thanks, However what if the $arr was multi array like:

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["question0"]=>
    string(14) "test 1 checked"
    ["homepage0"]=>
    string(8) "homepage"
    ["question1"]=>
    string(12) "hello test 1"
    ["question2"]=>
    string(20) "hello test 2 checked"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["question0"]=>
    string(14) "check number 1"
    ["homepage0"]=>
    string(8) "homepage"
     }
}

this case it cant work